# svn merge with conflicts

Tags: svn

So I have some branch that I want to merge into trunk. I used the following command:

svn merge -r N:HEAD ../trunk .

where N was obtained by:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy
```

This produces several conflicts (expected) and I choose postpone for each of them. Svn finally bails with:

```
svn: One or more conflicts were produced while merging r108047:109464 into
'.' --
resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge to apply the remaining
unmerged revisions
```

So I go through the conflicts one by one, manually fix the files, and issue svn resolved .

I'm thinking at this point that I can now re-run the exact same merge command, but when I do it shows no results, as if there is nothing left to merge. Compiling fails, because a ton of things aren't actually applied. I verify this with:

```
diff ../trunk .
```

And as expected there are tons of unapplied diffs (there are only a handful of things actually different in branch).

What an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but shouldn't your first parameter **..trunk** be the URL of your branch instead? Look at this and check [the sample code there to reintegrate branch to trunk](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html). Seems like you merged the changes from trunk to your branch (if you were in the working copy of your branch), which is good before reintegrating the branch. But now you have to go to your trunk working copy and run the command to merge the branch to the trunk. Sorry if i'm mistaking, most time I use tortoises to deal with svn so I'm not that familiar with the commands.

Comment: I actually want to merge trunk to branch and that's it. I think the problem is that after the branch was cut, features were explicitly removed. So when I merge trunk->branch I don't get those features back. And at this point it leaves me with a difficult-to-merge branch.

Comment: Oh, then you may want to fix your question, cause you said it the other way around: "I have some branch that I want to merge into trunk"